# get excerpt without images

Tags: functions, get-posts, excerpt

Is there any way to not get the images with get_the_excerpt()?  I am using a my_recent_post() function to pull posts onto the home page and I don't need to have it pull the images within the posts, just some of the text.

Here's the function that I am using:

```
function my_recent_post()
 {
  global $post;
  $html = "";
  $my_query = new WP_Query( array(
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'posts_per_page' => 3
  ));

  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

       $html .= "<div class='item'><a href=\"" . get_permalink() . "\"><span>" . get_the_date() . "</span></a>" . get_the_post_thumbnail() . "
       " . get_the_excerpt() . "</div> <div class='clear'></div>";

  endwhile; endif;

  return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'news', 'my_recent_post' );
```

Comment: `my_recent_post()` is not a generic WordPress function; please post the code of that function.

Comment: DAP!  Sorry, I meant to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`the_excerpt();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt) wordpress function to show **only** text. That function will filter out some html tags such as `<img>` , `<a>`. A useful alternative to show only plain text.

> #### Note -
>
> The `the_excerpt()` function internally uses `get_the_excerpt()` to get excerpt and return a new string by filtering tags such as `<img>`, `<a>` tags. It also wrap that string into `<p>` tags.

Comment: let me know if this isn't working..

Comment: Yep, looks like it's working.  I also have the Advanced Excerpt plugin installed, so I was able to weak it with that.  I'll keep messing with it a little more and if I hit a snag, I'll let you know.  Thanks for the input!