# Remove images from get_the_excerpt

Tags: functions, images, shortcode, excerpt

I'm using a custom function to create a shortcode that displays the latest blog post on the home page of a template. But I'm trying to NOT have it display any images.

I know I can use the Advanced Excerpt plugin to have it remove images, but the issue is that it will also remove images from the index.php feed which I want to keep which is using `the_excerpt()` in the template.

Here's my custom function that creates the shortcode:

```
function my_recent_news()
{
  global $post;
  $html = "";
  $my_query = new WP_Query( array(
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'posts_per_page' => 4
  ));

  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

       $html .= "

       <article>
       <span class=\"date\">" . get_the_date() . "</span>
       <h2><a href=\"" . get_permalink() . "\">" . get_the_title() . "</a></h2>
       " . get_the_excerpt() . "
       </article>
       ";
  endwhile; 

  endif;

  wp_reset_query();

  return $html;

}

add_shortcode( 'news', 'my_recent_news' );
```

I've posted something about this before:

[get excerpt without images](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61475/get-excerpt-without-images)

but the solution was to use the Advanced Excerpt plugin, but for this I am trying to use the excerpt on the home and the blog feed page but I want to preserve the `img` markup on the blog feed and remove the img tag from the custom shortcode.

I've tried to used just `the_excerpt()` in that custom shortcode function, but that just seems to break the whole function and display some really odd stuff.

I'm not too sure if I need to have a filter somewhere to strip that out or what. I'm also not sure that if I do need a filter, where that would go? Before the loop, after the loop, or does it need it's own constructed argument?

Comment: When I do a quick test images are stripped from the generated excerpt. Do you have images in the manually created excerpt?

Comment: @s_ha_dum: I have images within the posts.

Comment: Auto-generated excerpts, or user-defined excerpts? The former should not display images, but I believe the latter will.

Comment: @ChipBennett - You know what, I have no idea. And to be honest with you, I'm not sure where or how or what those are and where to modify them. This is the first time I am hearing about them today with my searching. If you have any insight on them, I'd be more than happy to know!

Comment: I would start with the [Codex entry on Excerpts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt).

Comment: @ChipBennett - Ahhh, ok. Then I think this is a user-defined one, I guess. Since I'm using `get_the_excerpt` to grab the post(s) data and then loop through it within the shortcode.

Comment: @ChipBennett : yes, I tested that too. If you put an `img` tag in the manual excerpt it will not be stripped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I did more digging and testing and I found by using `strip_tags()` basically removes any formatting within `get_the_excerpt()`.

Here's my updated code:

```
function my_recent_news()
{
  global $post;
  $html = "";
  $my_query = new WP_Query( array(
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'posts_per_page' => 4
  ));

  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

       $html .= "

       <article>
       <span class=\"date\">" . get_the_date() . "</span>
       <h2><a href=\"" . get_permalink() . "\">" . get_the_title() . "</a></h2>
       " . strip_tags(get_the_excerpt(), "<a>") . "
       </article>
       ";
  endwhile; 

  endif;

  wp_reset_query();

  return $html;

}

add_shortcode( 'news', 'my_recent_news' );
```

I added the `<a>` to preserve any hyperlinks within the excerpt of the post to display.

With this, I can preserve the markup with the blog feed page along with using the Advanced Excerpt plugin to assist with trimming the length and what not.

Comment: use `wp_reset_postdata` instead of `wp_reset_query` [for more info](http://www.poststat.us/properly-reset-wordpress-query/)

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [Codex entry for `get_the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt), you will find this:

> If the post does not have an excerpt, this function applies wp_trim_excerpt to the post content and returns that generated string with "[...]" at the end. wp_trim_excerpt is applied via the get_the_excerpt filter and can be removed.

The [`wp_trim_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt) function:

> Generates an excerpt from the content, if needed.
>
> The excerpt word amount will be 55 words and if the amount is greater
>   than that, then the string ' [...]' will be appended to the excerpt.
>   If the string is less than 55 words, then the content will be returned
>   as is.

So, you could either re-apply `wp_trim_excerpt()` to the `get_the_excerpt` filter, or else just output it directly:

```
   $html .= "

   <article>
   <span class=\"date\">" . get_the_date() . "</span>
   <h2><a href=\"" . get_permalink() . "\">" . get_the_title() . "</a></h2>
   " . wp_trim_excerpt() . "
   </article>
   ";
```

Comment: I might try that as well, but I think that I found a solution.

Comment: Great! Please be sure to post your solution as an answer.