# Modify RSS - remove image and add text

Tags: images, rss, excerpt

I'd like to remove the image from my RSS feed and add some "Read more" text. The code I have is

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[<?php 
echo strip_tags(the_excerpt_rss(), '<p><a>') . 
'<a href="' . the_permalink_rss() . '">Read more</a> at ' . 
the_permalink_rss(); 
?>]]></content:encoded>
```

But when this is run, I still have the image and the extra text is weirdly formatted. eg:

```
<content:encoded>![CDATA{ <img src="{imgpath}" alt="{imgAlt}"/>{postExcerpt}...{link}{link}<a href="">Read more</a> at]]>
```

Why does this happen?
I followed the instructions at [Remove images from get_the_excerpt](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123900/remove-images-from-get-the-excerpt) but it still shows images and the extra text is formatted strangely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `the_permalink_rss()` and `the_excerpt_rss()` do **echo** the output, **not return** it.

With your current snippet, replace  `the_excerpt_rss()` with:

```
apply_filters( 'the_excerpt_rss', get_the_excerpt() );
```

and replace `the_permalink_rss()` with:

```
esc_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink_rss', get_permalink() ) );
```

You could also use:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[
    <?php  the_excerpt_rss(); ?> 
    <a href="<?php the_permalink_rss(); ?>">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Read more', 'mydomain' );?>
    </a>
    <?php esc_html_e( 'at', 'mydomain' );?>
    <?php the_permalink_rss(); ?>
?>]]></content:encoded>
```

where you strip the RSS excerpt through the `the_excerpt_rss` filter or use the above approach to get the excerpt output to strip it.

You could also try using `printf` with:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[%s <a href="%s">%s</a> %s %s]]></content:encoded>
```

etc.

Comment: Final, WORKING, code is:

<content:encoded><![CDATA[
    <?php  echo strip_tags(apply_filters( 'the_excerpt_rss', get_the_excerpt() ), '<p><a>'); ?> 
    <a href="<?php the_permalink_rss(); ?>">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Read more', 'mydomain' );?>
    </a>
    <?php esc_html_e( ' at', 'mydomain' );?>
    <?php the_permalink_rss(); ?>
]]></content:encoded>

Thanks so much, @birgire.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working, yes there are few ways, I think it's like returning `null`, when functions only `echo` the output, so your previous example in the question, was like `strip_tags(null)`.@EddieS