# get_the_excerpt without images

Tags: excerpt

i'm using this function in my Wordpress index:

```
<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
```

But if the article contains an image in the first 50 words, I get the link of the image in this form:

> Immagine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRyZI.jpg

How can I exclude images from the excerpt?

Comment: You are wrong. [Here](http://prntscr.com/95xitp)'s the excerpt view, and [here](http://prntscr.com/95xj53)'s where the image is.

Comment: According with the codex, only manual excerpt can contains some allowed HTML because it is returned unchanged by `get_the_excerpt()`. Instead, if the excerpt is auto generated, all tags are removed, including images. Can you check that the excerpt if not manually created? Can you post the real code you are using?

Comment: Please look if this helps http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61475/get-excerpt-without-images

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following code.

```
   $content = get_the_excerpt();
   $content = preg_replace("/<img(.*?)>/si", "", $content);
   echo $content;
```

`preg_replace` will remove the image tag content from the post content.

Answer (score 2):

If you definitely want to show the excerpt from your content, and not from defined excerpt, you can use:

```
echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 55, '&hellip;' );
```

#### Resources:

- [`wp_trim_words()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words)
- [`wp_trim_excerpt()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt)
- [`get_the_excerpt()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt)
- [`get_the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content)